# Remove order by of IN(1 2 10 5 5 )?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, remove-if

The following query works, but MySQL sorts the results set:

```
SELECT STRINGTEXT FROM WEBSTRINGS WHERE GUI=0 AND LANGID='GB' AND TOKENID IN
(312,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62, 63,87,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311);
```

This means that when I grab this in my recordset the data for `TOKENID 312` is
at the end rather than being the first one, eg

I expected my resultset to come back in the following order of requests:

```
312,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,6 3,87,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311
```

but it comes back as:

```
47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,63,87 ,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311,312
```

Is there anyway to get MySQL to not do this for this query? I really need
them to come back as is.

Comment: Maybe you should do a `select STRINGTEXT,TOKENID ....` , then you will have the `TOKENID` and `STRINGTEXT` mapping in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '[ORDER BY FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)`

```
SELECT STRINGTEXT 
FROM WEBSTRINGS 
WHERE GUI=0 AND LANGID='GB' AND TOKENID IN (312,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62, 63,87,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311) 
ORDER BY FIELD (TOKENID,312,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,6 3,87,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311)
```

Comment: what is the problem? can you add the new code and error/output in the question. It should give the correct result.

Comment: It seems there is a typo in feed to `FIELD` function. *`...61,62,6 3,87,...`* should be *`...61,62,63,87,...`*. Remove the space in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STRINGTEXT 
FROM WEBSTRINGS 
WHERE GUI=0 
AND LANGID='GB' 
AND TOKENID IN (312,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,63,87,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311);
ORDER BY FIELD(TOKENID,312,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,61,62,63,87,88,89,90,208,210,249,309,310,311);
```

`field` documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field